# php field of all array members

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm looking for is simple but I have no idea about what to search on google.

I look for a simple PHP command to give me what I want without using loop:

```
$myarray= [
     ['id'=>5,'username'=>'aaa','password'=>'.....'],
     ['id'=>6,'username'=>'bbb','password'=>'.....'],
     ['id'=>7,'username'=>'ccc','password'=>'.....'],
     ['id'=>8,'username'=>'ddd','password'=>'.....'],
];
```

What I want to obtain:

```
array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')
```

Any simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (PHP 4 >= 4.0.6, PHP 5):

```
function get_usernames($a) {
    return $a['username'];
}

$values = array_map('get_usernames', $myarray);
```

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (this is available in >= PHP 5.5 [thanks for the tip kalley])

```
$myarray= [
    ['id'=>5,'username'=>'aaa','password'=>'.....'],
    ['id'=>6,'username'=>'bbb','password'=>'.....'],
    ['id'=>7,'username'=>'ccc','password'=>'.....'],
    ['id'=>8,'username'=>'ddd','password'=>'.....'],
];
$values = array_column($myarray, "username");
```

Comment: Wow, I learn something new every day!

Comment: Note that this is PHP 5.5 and above. But that is cool.

Comment: @kalley for lower than 5.5, here is a drop-in replacement: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: @TobiasKun I was just about to ask, how it's done with PHP lower than 5.5, because I'm on 5.4 - Seems `kalley` answered that for me. But, good one nonetheless, cheers

Comment: my php is 5.3 however array_column is amazing

Comment: i would use anonymous function:
`array_map(function($a){return $a['username'];}, $myarray)`